# Using Python Click, how do I add more than 5 options i.e. more than 5?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-click

Current code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive',
                                           'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--quiet', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(logs, process, quiet, check, scan):
```

If I add a 6th option to the main function, `pylint` complains about "Too many arguments (6/5) (52:0) [too-many-arguments]"

**I do not want to add an exception to pylint config file.**

I want to know how to pass more options to python @click.  Or do I need to restructure my file, so each option has its own `@click.command` and its own python function?

Sorry if this is duplicated, I could not find it since click is a very general term.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what are you trying to do with click, including usage of 'click' in main would be nice.

After testing module click, it just sends keyword arguments to decorated function 'main'.

Python gets keyword arguments as dictionary, so you normally use **kwargs to pass unlimited number of keyword arguments.

---

Example:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive', 'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--quiet', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(*args, **kwargs):
    click.echo(kwargs)
```

Result:

> {'logs': None, 'process': None, 'quiet': False, 'check': False,
>   'scan': None}
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

---

Your Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive', 'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--quiet', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(logs, process, quiet, check, scan):
    click.echo(locals())
```

Result:

> {'logs': None, 'process': None, 'quiet': False, 'check': False,
>   'scan': None}
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

---

As you see, using **kwargs yields same results. I don't know if this will affect module's behavior, but at least arguments are passed correctly. Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options to handle this `pylint` complaint.

#### Option 1: Inline Suppression

This option does not require that you add an exception to your `pylint` config file.
However, it does require that you add this extra inline comment: `# pylint: disable=too-many-arguments`
to your code as follows:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive',
                                           'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--quiet', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(logs, process, quiet, check, scan):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
```

This will disable `too-many-arguments` just for this function, not for your entire code base.

#### Option 2: Refactor Your Code

This option is a good choice whenever you have a complex command, which is doing many things, that also can be performed by multiple simple commands.

I'm not sure what your `main` `@click.command` is doing, but it seems as if it is trying to:

1. show logs
2. process some things
3. check some status
4. scan something

If that is the case, then could refactor this:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive',
                                           'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(logs, process, quiet, check, scan):
```

to:

```py
# @click.command has become Wclick.group.
@click.group()
def main(): pass

# We split off the functionality from `main` into sub-commands.
@main.command()
@click.argument("logtype", 
                type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive',  
                                   'archive-with-errors']))
def logs(logtype): pass


@main.command()
@click.argument("process_category", 
                type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
def process(process_category): pass


@main.command()
def check(): pass


@main.command()
@click.argument("arg")
def scan(arg): pass
```

This would solve the `too-many-arguments` complain, without suppressing `pylint`.
Now, with the refactored code, instead of invoking `main --logs=archive` you would invoke `main logs archive`.

#### Option 3:

Use the `*args` `**kwargs` trick:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', 
              type=click.Choice(['all', 'errors', 'no-errors', 'archive',
                                 'archive-with-errors']))
@click.option('--process', 
              type=click.Choice(['all', 'fix', 'spool', 'status', 'import']))
@click.option('--quiet', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--check', is_flag=True)
@click.option('--scan', nargs=1)
def main(*args, **kwargs):
```

as explained by @jupiterbjy [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345735/using-python-click-how-do-i-add-more-than-5-options-i-e-more-than-5/62346234#62346234)

This option would be suitable if you intend to pass the `*args` and `**kwargs` unchanged anyway.
If you would first pack `*args` and `**kwargs` in the function signature, and then unpack them manually, just to satisfy `pylint`, then you would be better off with either option 1 or 2.